# The most effective way to manipulate pixels in UIView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, core-graphics

In my project, I need to manipulate many pixels (get/change colors) in the `UIView`. I couldn't find a direct way to get/set pixels in `UIView`. The only way I can find, is to make a screen shot `UIImage`, then transfer the `UIImage` into `CGBitmapContext` data, and manipulate the data there.

Sample codes

**Get Pixels data**

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
  self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
  let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
  self.tempImageView.hidden = false

  let inImage:CGImageRef = image.CGImage!
  let context = image.createARGBBitmapContext(inImage)

  CGContextDrawImage(context, pixelsRect, inImage)

  let data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context)
  let dataType = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data)
```

Then I can do something directly to `dataType`.
Check which pixels I need to change colors.

**After Changed Pixels data**

Create the new image then add to UIView as a subview.

```
  let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
  let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)

  let bitmapBytesPerRow = Int(pixelsWide) * 4

  let finalcontext = CGBitmapContextCreate(BGData, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)

  let imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(finalcontext)
  let finalImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!, scale: BGImage.scale,orientation: BGImage.imageOrientation)

  imageView.image = finalImage
```

**My problem is, this whole process repeats very frequently, because lots of pixels in UIView change with FPS. So I'm looking for the most effective way to do this. For example, can I avoid manipulating all pixels through UIImage, just directly change them in UIView? would that be better? Could anyone give me suggestions?**

Comment: not sure if this will help but read this. https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios7-day-by-day-day-7-taking-snapshots-of-uiviews